# How to repeat a task that is using variable mapping and already has a loop?

Tags: ansible

I have something like this:

```
---

- name: Ansible Cisco DNAC Site Info
  hosts: dnac_servers
  vars_files:
    - pod2credentials.yml
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:

... other tasks omitted...

    - name: Delete_Areas_by_ID
      cisco.dnac.site_delete:
        dnac_host: "{{dnac_host}}"
        dnac_username: "{{dnac_username}}"
        dnac_password: "{{dnac_password}}"
        dnac_verify: "{{dnac_verify}}"
        dnac_port: "{{dnac_port}}"
        dnac_version: "{{dnac_version}}"
        dnac_debug: "{{dnac_debug}}"
        siteId: "{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ areas_ids }}"
```

The *areas_ids* variable has been defined in previous tasks and works.

The thing is that I need to repeat the Delete_Areas_by_ID a fix number of times (let's say 4 times or any other value that I can also define in separate variable)

I tried using a counter but it gave some error saying something like the task already had a loop.

I also tried putting that task in different playbook and the calling the task using *include_tasks* and *with_sequence* like this:

```
    - name: Delete_Areas_by_ID-Call_site_delete_area
      include_tasks:
        file: CSS_dnac_site_delete_area.yml
      with_sequence: start=1 end=4
```

But it's telling me that I cannot have nested mapping or something like that.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm a little unclear on your goal here. You have some list in `area_ids`. Do you want to repeat your `Delete Areas by ID` once for each item in that list? Or you only want to process some items in that list? Or the number of times the loop should iterate is independent of the length of the list? Or something else?

Comment: Hey @larsks! Thank you for taking the time. Yes, I have a list in *areas_ids* and I want to repeat the *Delete_Areas_by_ID* task a fix number of times for all the elements in the lists. What is happening hear is that this is hierarchical estructure in which I have one area and sub-areas. When I get the list, it is for all of them with no distinction made, and when I delete it will fail for "parent" area if still having a "child" area. Since I cannot always predict number of levels in hierarchy, I just want to repeat the whole task to make sure it will delete the parent area after x iterations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way of doing this is probably by using the `product` filter to iterate your loop additional times.  Let's say you want to iterate over `area_list` a total of three times. You could do this:

```
- name: Delete_Areas_by_ID
  cisco.dnac.site_delete:
    dnac_host: "{{dnac_host}}"
    dnac_username: "{{dnac_username}}"
    dnac_password: "{{dnac_password}}"
    dnac_verify: "{{dnac_verify}}"
    dnac_port: "{{dnac_port}}"
    dnac_version: "{{dnac_version}}"
    dnac_debug: "{{dnac_debug}}"
    siteId: "{{ item.1 }}"
  loop: "{{ [1,2,3]|product(areas_ids) }}"
```

---

Here's a runnable example of what we're doing. If we run this playbook:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    area_list:
      - areaA
      - areaB
      - areaC
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "Delete area ID: {{ item.1 }}"
      loop: "{{ [1,2,3]|product(area_list) }}"
```

We 'll see the following output:

```
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=[1, 'areaA']) => {
    "msg": "Delete area ID: areaA"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=[1, 'areaB']) => {
    "msg": "Delete area ID: areaB"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=[1, 'areaC']) => {
    "msg": "Delete area ID: areaC"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=[2, 'areaA']) => {
    "msg": "Delete area ID: areaA"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=[2, 'areaB']) => {
    "msg": "Delete area ID: areaB"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=[2, 'areaC']) => {
    "msg": "Delete area ID: areaC"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=[3, 'areaA']) => {
    "msg": "Delete area ID: areaA"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=[3, 'areaB']) => {
    "msg": "Delete area ID: areaB"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=[3, 'areaC']) => {
    "msg": "Delete area ID: areaC"
}
```

You can see from the output that we're iterating over `area_list` three times.

---

Note that the values in the list we're using with `product` don't matter; you'd get the same value if you were to write:

```
[0, 0, 0]|product(area_list)
```

Etc.